# Internet Explorer (IE11) not saving specifc object value returned from GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, http-method

I'm experiencing a rather weird issue where IE (IE11) is having trouble saving a variable returned from a GET, it's one specific variable. The other variables returned in the object are valid data and the one variable that isn't working in IE is working correctly in other browsers.

Below is a sample of my actual code with results.

```
$.get("myPHPscript.php", function( data ) {
    // Parse result
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    jobs = obj.jobs;
    // Loop through object
    for(var key in jobs)
    {
        name = jobs[key].name;  // Valid data in all 3 browers
            console.log("Name: " + name);
        id = jobs[key].id;      // Valid data in all 3 browers
            console.log("ID: " + id);
        status = jobs[key].status;  // Valid data in Firefox, Chrome but EMPTY in IE.
            console.log("Status: " + status);
    }
});
```

Here is a sample of the data returned in the GET call that I have from the browser network inspect capability. This is identical in all 3 browsers.

```
{  
   "jobs":[  
      {
         "id":"4142",
         "name":"Test",
         "status":"closed"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4143",
         "name":"testtttttt",
         "status":"open"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4144",
         "name":"Test job subclient",
         "status":"open"
      }
    ]
}
```

Here is a picture of the results from the browsers with the above code.

[image]

**Note:** If I save obj to a global variable and try to access status in IE console, it returns valid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't resolve the issue, changing the variable name from "status" to anything else produces valid data in IE.

According to Microsoft, status isn't a reserved word in Javascript

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0779sbks%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

So I'm not sure what was producing the issue to begin with.

**Does not work in IE**

```
status = jobs[key].status;  // Valid data in Firefox, Chrome but EMPTY in IE.
console.log("Status: " + status);
```

**Does work in IE**

```
status1 = jobs[key].status;  // Valid data all 3 browsers
console.log("Status: " + status1);
```

Comment: `jobs[key]['status']` -- `status` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

`jobs[key]['status']` -- `status` is a reserved word so it must be in quotes.